# How can I remove the default window of a select in HTML

Tags: html

[image: default window]

I don't understand how to disable the default window of a select. In this case I have no options and so the window would remain empty. That's why I want to remove it. Can anyone tell me how to do this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it is possible to remove that default option. One thing you can do is, while the select is empty, use the disabled property.

```
<select disabled></select>
```

You can then use javascript to fill out the select and remove the disabled property.